# security of my gmail had to be changed in less secure apps - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gmail

I'm working on asp.net MVC web project and I want to send mail from a web page to my mail box. I followed this link to do that

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sourabh_mishra1/sending-an-e-mail-using-asp-net-mvc/

I used a gmail account to send and receive emails. but google asked me to `turn on  less secure apps` and it warns me several times that I will lost my mail security after turns it on.

is it possible to tell me what should I do? Appreciate any help.

and also another question: I had to write my email's password in my code clearly

```
 smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            //here
            ("username", "password");// Enter seders User name and password  
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return View("Index", _objModelMail);
```

does it matter in security of my web and my email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**send mail**

You may have used `single-factor authentication (SFA)` or `two-factor authentication (2FA)`. You need to adjust settings for each. I think [this](https://galleryserverpro.com/use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server-even-when-using-2-factor-authentication-2-step-verification/) link help you for `smtp` setting and `gmail` setting.

**password hard-coded**

Usually this isn't done as hard-coded. You can set password like this(`dotnetnuke`):

[image: smtp]

Comment: really thank you for your help. very nice advises. thanks.I will  work on it and will let you know. thanks